# Get real IP address Virtualbox for LDAP configuration

Tags: ubuntu, networking, virtualbox, virtual-machine, ldap

I'm planning to setup a LDAP configuration between two ubuntu virtual machines on my windows machine.

So I installed two ubuntu 16.04 virtual machines on my windows machine using VirtualBox. Now I want to get a real IP so I can connect to the virtual machine from anywhere.

When I use `NAT` it sets up the IP as 10.0.4.14 and when I choose `Bridged adapter` or `Host-only Adapter` then I don't get any internet connection.

Could anyone please advise how I can get a "real" IP when using Virtualbox with Ubuntu 16.04 so I can use this IP for LDAP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Vagrant

I've moved to using Vagrant + `Vagrantfiles` exclusively to do this with Virtualbox. This is a file that I use that sets 2 VMs on my laptop.

Characteristics of this `Vagrantfile`:

- VMs are Ubuntu 16.04 (xenial64)
- VMs request public IP addresses from your LAN's DHCP server
- VMs will utilize your Virtualbox Host's NIC's interface (see file)
- I left the name of the `centos/7` image in the file if you want to switch

#### Resources for Vagrant

- [Main site](https://www.vagrantup.com/)
- [Installing Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/installation/)
- [publicly available catalog of Vagrant boxes](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search)
- [CentOS/7 box file](https://app.vagrantup.com/centos/boxes/7)

#### Sample Vagrantfile

```
$ cat Vagrantfile
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :


##############
### References
# - https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/machine_settings.html
# - https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/tips.html
# - https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/forwarded_ports.html
##############

#unless Vagrant.has_plugin?("HostManager")
#  raise 'HostManager plugin not installed!'
#end

require 'digest/sha1'

uniqID = "_" + (Digest::SHA1.hexdigest Dir.pwd()).slice(0..8)
image  = "ubuntu/xenial64"
#image = "centos/7"

if Vagrant::Util::Platform.windows? then
  interfaces = [
    "Intel(R) 82583V Gigabit Network Connection",
    "Intel(R) 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection",
  ]
elsif Vagrant::Util::Platform.darwin? then
  interfaces = [
    "en0: Wi-Fi (AirPort)",
    "en1: Wi-Fi (AirPort)",
  ]
else
  interfaces = [
    "eth0",
    "eth1",
    "wlan0",
  ]
end


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  vboxName1 = "box-101"
  hostname1 = "box101"
  config.vm.define "#{vboxName1}" do |front|
    front.vm.box = "#{image}"
    #front.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.101"
    front.vm.network :public_network, use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true, bridge: interfaces
    front.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 512]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "#{hostname1}#{uniqID}"]
    end
  end
  vboxName2 = "box-102"
  hostname2 = "box102"
  config.vm.define "#{vboxName2}" do |front|
    front.vm.box = "#{image}"
    #front.vm.network :private_network, ip: "192.168.56.102"
    front.vm.network :public_network, use_dhcp_assigned_default_route: true, bridge: interfaces
    front.vm.provider :virtualbox do |v|
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--memory", 512]
      v.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--name", "#{hostname2}#{uniqID}"]
    end
  end
end
```

#### Usage

*start both VMs*

```
 $ vagrant up
```

*start one VM at time*

```
 $ vagrant up box-101
 $ vagrant up box-102
```

*ssh to VM box-101*

```
$ vagrant ssh box-101
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-130-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

  Get cloud support with Ubuntu Advantage Cloud Guest:
    http://www.ubuntu.com/business/services/cloud

0 packages can be updated.
0 updates are security updates.


/usr/bin/xauth:  file /home/vagrant/.Xauthority does not exist
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$
```

*confirm IP address*

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ ip a l
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:97:71:8a:f0:d8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global enp0s3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::97:71ff:fe8a:f0d8/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:e6:43:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.12.208/24 brd 172.16.12.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee6:43ac/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$
```

**NOTE:** It's expected behavior that you'll have 2 interfaces. Vagrant/Virtualbox always sets up a interface similar to `enp0s3` which is associated to the `10.0.2.15/24` interface. This is the NIC that Vagrant is using when SSH'ing into the VM among other things.

#### Testing network connectivity

With the above `Vagrantfile` and the 2 VMs started up (box-101 & box-102) we can verify 3 scenarios of network connectivity. **NOTE:** Before we start take note of the VM's IP addresses.

***Background***

*For box-101 (172.16.12.208):*

```
$ ip a l enp0s8
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:e6:43:ac brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.12.208/24 brd 172.16.12.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fee6:43ac/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

*For box-102 (172.16.12.116):*

```
$ ip a l enp0s8
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:df:3b:06 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.16.12.116/24 brd 172.16.12.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fedf:3b06/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

***Scenarios***

*Scenario #1: box-102 → box-101*

```
## On box-101 run:
$ nc -l 12345

## On box-102 run:
$ curl -v telnet://172.16.12.208:12345
* Rebuilt URL to: telnet://172.16.12.208:12345/
*   Trying 172.16.12.208...
* Connected to 172.16.12.208 (172.16.12.208) port 12345 (#0)
^C
```

*Scenario #2: Virtualbox Host → box-101*

```
## On box-101 run:
$ nc -l 12345

# On Virtualbox Host
$ curl -v telnet://172.16.12.208:12345
* Rebuilt URL to: telnet://172.16.12.208:12345/
*   Trying 172.16.12.208...
* Connected to 172.16.12.208 (172.16.12.208) port 12345 (#0)
^C
```

*Scenario #3: Remote Server → box-101*

```
## On box-101 run:
$ nc -l 12345

## In Remote Server
$ curl -v telnet://172.16.12.208:12345
* About to connect() to 172.16.12.208 port 12345 (#0)
*   Trying 172.16.12.208...
* Connected to 172.16.12.208 (172.16.12.208) port 12345 (#0)
^C
```

Comment: I've tried your updated `Vagrantfile` and it get stuck in the `Configuring and enabling network interfaces...`  as shown here https://i.stack.imgur.com/xaWuA.png I tried the fix found here https://github.com/hashicorp/vagrant/issues/7876#issuecomment-252131829 but still the same problem.